# How do you apply scale within geometry nodes, so that each instance has the same scale for procedural textures?

Tags: materials, shaders, geometry-nodes

I have the following geometry nodes setup for a succulent plant.
[image]

I want to create a material for it to add details like dust, and other imperfections, but the textures are scaled down along with each instance, which is predictable behavior, but is there a way to bypass this behavior so that the mesh as a whole has the same scale for shading?
[image]

Comment: did you try to use realize instances?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out, what I was looking for was the "Realize Instances" node. Thanks Chris!